# change the playback frequency (pitch Human sound to Animal sound) of a .wav file?

Tags: iphone, avplayer

How can I change the playback frequency (pitch Human sound to Animal sound) of a .wav file programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use dirac library which comes up with having some sample codes ,free and easy to implement.